# Firebase - email is not defined

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I am trying to build a function that allows user to change their password. The problem is when I am getting the current user's data it shows that the email is null.

Everything works on Firebase, users are creating in Firebase auth system.

Here is a part of my code

```
reauthenticate = (currentPassword) => {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentuser;
    var cred = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(user.email, currentPassword);
    user.reauthenticateWithCredential(cred);
}

reauthenticate(currentPassword).then(() => {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentuser;
    user.updatePassword(newPassword).then(() => {
        alert("Password changed");
        window.location.replace("./index.html");
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
});
```

What console shows is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email') at reauthenticate (password.js:15:64) at changePassword (password.js:27:9)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its currentUser not currentuser. Capital U.

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
```